# Interactive image AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I have created a Web site using `AngularJS` and HTML, I want to load a static image and to create interactive spots on this image.

When I hover mouse on this spot, I want some popup notification with some information.

Which library should I use? I checked OpenLayers but I dont know if it is the right choice for what i want to do

I think a solution like this:
[image]

Comment: why can't you just use map/area tags dynamically added to image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html image map. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>

<script>
$( "area" ).hover(
  function() {
    alert('This is ' + $( this ).attr("alt"));
  }
);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Source:
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)
[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: thanks, one question: it is possible to insert an icon on the <area> ?

Comment: No, it does not work that way. Your icons should be a part of the image already. And if you want the icons animated, you can use css animation on the image or a gif image.

Comment: ok so if i insert icon in the image, it is possible to create a popup like my image or i can do only an alert?

Comment: Yes you can create pop up. The logic to create the pop up would replace calling the alert function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i try to do that

Comment: I can but that is a different question - please create it and post the link here. But to give a hint - you can use jquery ui.